# Jade remove "/>" from the end of input tags

Tags: pug

Is it possible for Jade output to exclude the "/>" closing of void element, such as input?

So that:

```
input
```

is output as

```
<input>
```

not

```
<input/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what doctype you use.
If you set the doctype to HTML5 ('!!!', 'doctype html', ...) then it is not necessary to close the "self-closing" tags.

You can try to set the doctype to something else (anything else then HTML5) , then Jade will place the closing tags.

You can find the available doctypes in the [references](http://jade-lang.com/reference/)

> Another reference: [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Comment: Even with "!!!" or "doctype 5" I am still getting them. Can it be overridden via an option?

Comment: +Edifice can you provide an example where input tags (for instance) are not self closing in Jade?

Comment: `!!!<breakline>input` will produce: `<!DOCTYPE html><input>`  and `doctype basic<breakline>input` will produce: `<!DOCTYPE html><input/>`

Comment: `!!!`, `doctype html`, `doctype 5` are refers to HTML5, where it is not necessary to close the self closing tags. All the other doctypes will add the closing slash.